# Get the text next to @ char in string with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm implementing a mentions mechanism in a React based chat application. When the user types @ in the textarea I am opening a list of members of the group and performing a search in that list using the text which comes after the @ char. The code for search query extraction is as follows:

```
const regexp = /@(\S+)/g;
const text = regexp.exec(message);
let mentionText = '';
mentionText = text ? text[0] : '@';
```

This works only if there's 1 @ char in the string. For example, if there's an e-mail written in the message text before the @ char which opens the list of members, this will not work because I'm taking the first item in the array which is the e-mail.

Is there a better/more elegant/better working way to get the search term from the entered string? I basically need to take the text which comes after @ char which is not an e-mail, for example. Yes, to be more precise - text before @ char which has a heading space. That way I can tell for sure that the user wants to write a mention. Basically I think it should be like this  `@`.  If there's a space and a @ sign next to it - the user is writing a mention. The problem is how to identify that  `@` - with a heading space.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your goal to extract the text after the final `@`?

Comment: Yes, to be more precise - text before @ char which has a heading space. That way I can tell for sure that the user wants to write a mention. So it should be like this ` @`.  If there's a space and a @ sign next to it - the user is writing a mention.

Comment: no, it's pretty straight forward; only other way would be something like `(\s+|^)@(\S+)`

Answer (score 1):

RegEx has an internal parameter which stores the last match index so that when you run it the next time, you get the next match. Just keep running the regex in a while loop.

```js
const message = "@player with player@email went to @place."

const regexp = /@(\S+)/g;
const mentions = [];
let text;
while (text = regexp.exec(message)) {
    let mentionText = '';
    mentionText = text ? text[1] : '@';
    mentions.push(mentionText)
}
console.log("mentions", mentions)
```

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is that email should not be considered as a mention.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the regular expression, alternate between a space and the start of the string. Then lose the global flag (you're only looking for one match, after all). Use optional chaining to keep things concise.

```
const mentionText = /(?: |^)@(\S+)/.exec(message)?.[1] ?? '@';
```

Comment: Thanks, this just doesn't cover the case if the mention is the first thing in the message. In that case it will not have a heading space.

Comment: I thought your comment indicated that you only wanted a match before a @ with a leading space. Alternating with the start of the string is trivial.